# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (Download dynamic generated file)

Tags: c#, io

Upon button click, user should be able to download QueryReuslt.xlsx, this file is generated with database query results.is the error saying that 2 user are trying to read QueryResult.xlsx at the same time? how should i avoid this?

```
try
    {
        getDataForExcel();
        String fileName = "QueryResult.xlsx";

        // Construct the datatable programetically
        DataTable datatable = ds.Tables[0];

        string XLSPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EXPORTPATH"].ToString();//temp path to store the XLS file

        string excelFileName = XLSPath + @"\QueryResult.xlsx";

        ExportDataSet(datatable, excelFileName);

        // write file to client
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(excelFileName);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }


private void ExportDataSet(DataTable table, string excelFileName)
{
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(excelFileName, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

        var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
        sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
        string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

        uint sheetId = 1;
        if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
        {
            sheetId =
                sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
        }

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();


        // Construct column names
        List<String> columns = new List<string>();
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
            headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
        }

        // Add the row values to the excel sheet
        sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
        {
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
            foreach (String col in columns)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
                newRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are 2 (or more) requests at the same time? Your code always uses the same path for the generated file.

Comment: Hi Vesan, if i use a different filename for every request, and delete the file after request end, will it solve the problem?

Comment: No idea if it will fix your problem, but I would definitely generate unique names/paths for every request. Just make sure you delete the files afterwards (ideally in a `finally` block).

Comment: If you tend to keep existing files, unique file names with additional number as index should work. But if it simply removing old results and create new file with same name, use `System.IO.File.Delete(excelFileName)` on `finally` block.

Comment: @Senw The method you have posted above and the method ExportDataSet are working on the same file. Your issue is in ExportDataSet. Show me the code and I can point you to the issue.

Comment: Hi CodingYoshi, i have added ExportDataSet method code. To elaborate more, the error occurs when the result set return 360+ rows.